# Компиляция Python 3.6 + PyQt с использованием cx_Freeze

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Итоговая папка с проектом занимает достаточно много, ~150 мб, обнаружил, что в папке содержатся все модули PyQt, а не только используемые, думаю основной объем именно оттуда, какие есть способы уменьшить итоговый размер файла?

Comment: Можно указать какие модули не нужно включать в файл

Comment: Слышал об этом, хотелось бы посмотреть на какой-то конкретный пример setup'а под pyqt

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27436548/5909792 смотрите excludes

Comment: Тогда в таком случае придется указывать все библиотеки, используемые в проекте? Или можно как-то выделить только модули конкретного пакета, а остальное по умолчанию?

Comment: В примере весь пакет был указан, например PyQt5. Да и что вам мешает перечислить ненужные Qt модули, что попали в exe?